# Using PHP Slim Framework inside of Classes

Tags: php, frameworks, slim

I can't seem to get the Slim framework to access functions inside the scope of a PHP class:

```
<?php

class Controller {
    private $app;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->app = new Slim();

        $this->app->get('/', $this->home);

        $this->app->run();
    }

    public function home() {
        echo 'hi';
    }
}
```

This causes the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message
>   'Undefined property: Controller::$home' in
>   /Users/Oliver/Dropbox/Sites/grapevine/application/controller.php:9
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Users/Oliver/Dropbox/Sites/grapevine/application/controller.php(9):
>   Slim::handleErrors(8, 'Undefined prope...', '/Users/Oliver/D...', 9,
>   Array) #1 /Users/Oliver/Dropbox/Sites/grapevine/public/index.php(14):
>   Controller->__construct() #2 {main} thrown in
>   /Users/Oliver/Dropbox/Sites/grapevine/application/controller.php on
>   line 9

I have tried doing this instead:

```
$this->app->get('/', $this->home());
```

But then the routing is ignored, and 'hi' is displayed on every page, not just '/'.

Comment: At least [on the Slim site's demo](http://www.slimframework.com/), what's passed is an "anonymous" function. I'm not sure that you can pass the reference to class method this way.

Comment: Note as well, to use anonymous functions, you need at least [version 5.3.0](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Comment: According to the docs you can pass a non anonymous function.  It is backwards compatible with 5.2.  My question is thoough: what is the fuss about static?  WHY is it complaining about it?  I'm not really familiar with the purpose of using static.  I'll go peruse the question archive for more information, but in the mean time if anyone has any insight about why slim is complaining for a static member function I'd appreciate it.

Comment: not related to the question, but looking at the error message, I got a good idea: code inside your dropbox when working on personal project and don't worry about checking in the code! thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Use the callback syntax for member functions:

```
$this->app->get('/', array($this, 'home'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should work (it might be neccessary to change your home-function to be static, though!):

```
$this->app->get('/', "Controller::home");
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I am getting this error: Message: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method Controller::home() should not be called statically. What do you mean by static?

Comment: I did have to change it to static, but I want to be able to access the class and its properties, like so: http://hastebin.com/wesukifufu.coffee. However, then I get the following error: 
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /Users/Oliver/Dropbox/Sites/grapevine/application/controller.php on line 16

Comment: You can't use `$this` in a static context. Use `Controller::$test` instead. edit: I almost forgot, of course you have to make $test static too.

Answer (score 1):

I have [this solution](https://gist.github.com/OzzyCzech/7230064) with constructor injection from Slim internal container

Basically the main magic is hidden in `__call` function

```
class App extends Slim
 public function __call($name, $params) {
  return function () use ($name, $params) {
  list($class, $action) = explode('_', $name . '_handle'); // default method is handle

  $args = [];
  $class = new \ReflectionClass($class);
  $constructor = $class->getConstructor();
  foreach ($constructor->getParameters() as $param) {
   $args[] = ($param->name === 'app') ? $this : $this->container->get($param->name);
  }
  $controller = $class->newInstanceArgs($args);
  return call_user_func([$controller, $action], func_get_args() + $params);
  };
 }
}
```

controller need to have App in constructor params:

```
class Homepage {

 public $app;

 public function __construct(\App $app) {
  $this->app = $app;
 }
}
```

And index.php have just router settings

```
$app = new \App();
$app->get('/', $app->Homepage());
$app->run(
```

See whole code here https://gist.github.com/OzzyCzech/7230064